# How to change legend name in Grafana (Infinity plugin)

Tags: grafana, dynatrace

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeQ61.png)

Hi, I am relatively new to Grafana in general.

I have tried to use the Infinity plugin to configure the data by parsing from Dynatrace via CSV and configured with UQL for a dashboard and I am trying to change the name for each values in the legend.

Is it possible to change the name of each legend?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbuYO.png)

I have tried to use the override settings and the legend settings in the normal menu.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.